# Please help, us this shirk?

Tags: halal-haram, sunni, shirk, kufr, kuffar

Salam, so this has started worrying me a lot today

So in about December I started reading the Harry Potter books and it took me about six months to finish them

In the series, there’s a “spell” that’s called “expecto patronum” which translates to “I await a guardian” and then a transparent animal appears infront of them that’s based on their personality (it can change though to the same as the person you love’s) and it can send messages to people or get rid of certain monsters, and the person must think of a really happy memory or thought to be able to make the animal appear while saying the words and sometimes me and I’d speak to others about this about what animals would appear for us

Also there’s another “spell” in the last film that translates to “I protect to the highest limit” and it makes a strong shield, and my profile picture on WhatsApp used to be of a person from the film using this one with two others and it was in my bio on it as well

Is this shirk? As of course, one of Allah’s beautiful names is The Protector and he protects us

Can someone please reply to this as soon as possible as it’s worrying me a lot

Thank you very much

Comment: Fıqh is vital in Islam but rather your heart. What does it say? If you believe it is part of your religion or ascribe a meaning to Islam, there is a problem. Otherwise, it is science finction.

Answer (score 0):

The seriers of "Harry Potter" depicts some scenes that is actually controversial if we take it seriously. I think you can just watch the series if you want though watching it is makruh at least.

The Avengers, and its various series also contains controversial issue. Like it shows us a perverted concept of protecting humanity.

Nobody take these seriously...like these kind of stuff can save us really. So it will not fall into the domain of Shirk.
But as these movies introduce us with a controversial concept that actually teach us our religion , so you had better lower your attraction to these. And in case of using profile picture ... I discourage you in that case